# label x assigned to a block which is not a set

Tags: antlr4

trying out upgrading antlr4, I have 2 lines in the grammar that produce the error message:

> label tok assigned to a block which is not a set

Specifically for a grammar line that looks like this:

```
contextRadius: tok=('radius' 'change-authorize-nas-ip') (IP4_ADDRESS|IP6_ADDRESS) 'encrypted' 'key' ID 'port' INT_TOK 'event-timestamp-window' INT_TOK 'no-reverse-path-forward-check'
    ;
```

What does this imply, exactly - to be a "block which is not set" and is there a general solution?

Comment: I figured this out, basically I think ANTLR is implying that I'm not using the token.

In one case I just removed the "tok=".

In the second case, I removed a single set of parens that were not needed.

So

    (IP4_ADDRESS)

became just:

    IP4_ADDRESS

So now the generator tool produces code, but the lexer and parser have compilation errors.  Will report that separate issue on a new thread.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The improper label is the following:

```
tok=('radius' 'change-authorize-nas-ip')
```

In this case, ANTLR doesn't know whether to assign the token `'radius'` or the token `'change-authorize-nas-ip'` to the label `tok`. Starting with ANTLR 4, rather than generate code with unclear semantics an error is produced. You'll want to either remove the label `tok` or move it to the intended item. In other words, use one of the following three forms.

```
('radius' 'change-authorize-nas-ip')
(tok='radius' 'change-authorize-nas-ip')
('radius' tok='change-authorize-nas-ip')
```

The reason labels are allowed on blocks in grammars is to support items like the following. This block is a *set*, meaning the contents can be collapsed to matching exactly one token from a fixed set of allowed tokens. The particular item matched by the set is then assigned to `x`.

```
x=('a' | 'b')
```

Comment: Do all the items in the set have to be the same type? I'm getting this error and my block produces at most one item, but it chooses from 3 alternates of different types.